# React Child List Component

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I am learning react, what is the best practice for the following scenario? 
(Note just typed this up - not perfect, just meant to illustrate what I'm trying to do).  Given this data -

```
const person = {
   name: "",
   tasks: [
     {name: "", done: false }
   ]
 }
```

I want a form to edit both the name and the tasks at the same time - add, delete and edit the fields of the tasks.

What I was thinking:

```
<PersonForm>
 <PersonName />
 <TaskList />
</PersonForm>
```

The name can be easily edited by the example given by react documentation:

```
class PersonForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state  = {
            name: "",
            tasks: [
                {name: "", done: false }
            ]
        };
    }
    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <PersonName name={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            <TaskList tasks={this.state.tasks} 
               deleteTask={this.deleteTask} 
               addTask={this.addTask} 
               updateTask={this.updateTask}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        );
    }
}

class PersonName extends
   render() {
    return (
     <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" name="name" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
        </label>
     )
   }
}
```

I know the recommendation is lifting state up.  So I could put the addTask, removeTask and updateTask callback methods in PersonForm.

```
class PersonForm extends React.Component {
. . .
addTask = event => {
  this.setState(prev => ({ tasks: [...prev, {name: "", done: false}]}));
}
removeTask = key => {
  this.setState(prev => ({ tasks: prev.filter(t => t.key !== key) });
}
updateTask = ???...
. . .
```

But,

It seems to me the best way to encapsulate functionality would be for the addTask, deleteTask, updateTask functionality to be in the TaskList component. Am I wrong?

It seems like otherwise PersonForm would get huge (in a real world example). Would this mean TaskList would need state?

Basically,

1. What is the best practice for this sub-list scenario?
2. If callbacks from the top are the answer, how to update the task data?

Answer (score 1):

Moving some logic outside of the component when it starts getting huge makes sense but at the same time it's convenient to keep all form state in one place. You could use `ref` on child component to retrieve it's state but it's an ugly solution and considered a bad practice. I believe in my experience I haven't encountered a very huge forms so even they were big components it was pretty fine to read/manage all the state there. But if you'd really want to move some logic out of it I think you could, for example, use the new context API to store the form's state (or just tasks list's state) and subscribe to it in `PersonForm` component (to read) and in `TaskList` (to read and change).